# Is it a good practice to have embedded jetty and GRPC server running in the same JVM?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Our organization is looking into implementing new internal APIs using GRPC. 
Currently, we have a microservice that is serving internal/external requests using embedded Jetty. We want to make internal communication between services to be done over GRPC.

So, we'll have 2 servers running on the same VM: jetty and GRPC. Is it a good practice, any red flags with that approach?

We do not want to split that said microservice into 2 to save costs. We should be able to run the app on the same number of VMs.

Comment: A "server" is something that sits right there listening for incoming traffic. In your case you would have to use different ports. I don't see why you can't have those running at the same time. You would pay performance-wise, if any, but that's about it.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but is it a good practice? How much of a toll performance-wise will GRPC server impose on my VM?

Comment: I don't think anyone can measure your environment's performance but you. It's a very specific to your infrastructure. All we know is that you are using Jetty, but no metrics whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently special or wrong about having Jetty and gRPC in the same JVM. The main point of potential trouble is just that you will have two ports exposed instead of one; that might matter for service discovery or firewalls.